# Error when logging in to Retail Link in automation anywhere RPA

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I want to log in to Walmart's retail link platform but when I perform the step that the documentation gives us for the POST call, I cannot take it in a web browser, I only receive success

The procedure I follow is the following

1. use the POST method
   [method post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbYED.png)
2. I receive the confirmation
   [success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNA0M.png)

Would you like to know what steps should be followed ?
Does the solution need to be implemented in Python or Javascript or some other technology?